# XML Serialization from class instance in Ruby with custom attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

Let's say that I have the following classes in Ruby:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :car
end

class Car
  attr_accessor :maker
end
```

Is there a gem in ruby that would allow me to serialize an instance of Person to XML and allow me to add custom attributes to the XML tags as well? (preferably a declarative api, where I can either assign the attributes to a specific tag inside the declaration of the `attr_accessor`, or for all tags at once as a hash returned from a function).

For example, I want to achieve something like this:

```
<Person>
  <Name origin="American">
     Mark
  </Name>
  <Car from="My friend">
    <Maker>
      Honda
    </Maker>
  </Car>
</Person>
```

https://github.com/rails/activemodel-serializers-xml does not allow you to set custom attributes (the attributes function in the examples actually sets the tags, not the attributes). Overriding `to_xml` does not let me modify existing tags, and I'd rather not add new ones. Other gems such as Nokogiri seem to have a more hands on approach, where you manually build the xml instead of deriving it from the definition of a class. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could  include the module `XML::Mapping` you can see an example [here](https://multi-io.github.io/xml-mapping/XML/Mapping.html#method-c-add_node_class).

You can call all node factory methods from the body of the mapping classes.

In order to set customs attributes in the XML document:

```rb
require 'xml/mapping'

class Person
  include XML::Mapping

  text_node :from, "@from" # ,:default_value=>"My friend" migth works as well

  def initialize
    # add this to the initialize method 
    # if :default_value=>"My friend" in text_node do not works
    @from = "My friend"
  end
end
```

Comment: I did stumble upon this library as well a while ago, but forgot to update my post. Works wonders for me, and is exactly what I was looking for. Marking this as the accepted answer, thanks.